# How to declare an iterator variable for unknown container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

How to declare an iterator for unknown STL container? for example, I want to write a function that recieve container and print it all using iterators:

```
template <class Container> void print(Container c) {
    // how to declare iterator???????
    my_iterator = c.begin();
    while(my_iterator!=c.end()) {
        cout << *my_iterator << endl;
        my_iterator++;
    }
}
```

Comment: c++11: `auto it = c.begin();`

Comment: It's not "unknown" - knowing template type argument is as good as knowing the type :)

Comment: Note that in this particular case, you should pass the container by `const` reference, to avoid making an unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 10):

In C++03, you would need to get the iterator type from the container type explicitly:

```
typename Container::iterator it;
typename Container::const_iterator cit;
```

In C++11, you can just use `auto`:

```
auto my_iterator = c.begin();  // iterator in this case
auto my_iterator = c.cbegin(); // const_iterator always
```

Also note, as suggested my @Matthieu, that you can use a range based for loop in C++11, to simplify the code:

```
template <class Container> 
void print(const Container& c)
{
    for (const auto& elem : c)
        cout << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: In C++11, there is actually even better: `for (auto const& element: c)`

Comment: @MatthieuM. of course, good point! I was concentrating on a literal interpretation of the question. I will add something about the range based loop.

Answer (score 0):

Go for:

```
for (auto& var : container)
{
  cout << var << endl;
}
```

To display each elements of your container (and of any other type of container, even string or vector or map , ...)